# Android Placeholder\Hint text in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin forms to build a cross platform app and I have an issue with placeholder text for Entry elements when they render in Android. The placeholder displays as expected in iOS but it's blank in Android. Having searched in Google I understand the issue: basically the Android text editor field doesn't have a Placeholder property and you have to set it's Hint instead.

What I don't understand is how to do this programmatically. I know how to extend the Editor class, but how do I then tell Xamarin forms that for Android the Entry cell should relate to my custom Editor element which does some stuff to assign the Hint when the Placeholder is set? Or is there a better way? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xamarin forms Entry view has a PlaceHolder property that works on android as well:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Placeholder/

This is an example for defining a plcaeholder for an entry:

```
Entry myEntry = new Entry
{
   Placeholder = "This is a placeholder"
};
```

If you are using a custom renderer, you can still use the placeholder in your PCL project with your custom entry or you can use the Hint property of the control in your custom renderer in the following manner:

```
public class MyEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {                                
            Control.Hint = "This is my placeholder";                           
        }         

    }
}
```

If it still doesn't work for you, I suggest that you update your Xamarin.Forms nuget package to the latest version.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Must have been on an older version. Updating the Nuget packages fixed it.

Comment: Glad I could help :)